# Linq to Sql query reuse

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq-to-sql

Let's say we have a view V1 and V2 that is declared like:

```
create view V2 as
select V1.*, V2.C1, V2.C2, V2.C3
from V1
join V2 on V1.Key = V2.Key
where bla-bla
```

So V2 narrows down the result set of V1 and adds some joins. And there is a retrieval routine in C#

```
IEnumerable<V1> GetData(MyFilter filter, MySortOrder order) {}
```

I want to reuse with V2. Is it possible without performing joins in L2S rather than in database? Should i manually create a base class in the database context or something?

Comment: Depends on the use of filter and order arguments, can you send the code of GetData method ?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Because GetData() uses properties of V1 only and they're duplicated in V2.

Comment: Can you easily split in two methods IEnumerable<V1> FilterAndSort(IEnumerable<V1> allData, MyFilter filter, MySortOrder order) ?

Comment: If you declare the class `V2` and decorate it with `L2S` attributes, you can just use directly.  `L2S` doesn't know or care about views vs. tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with creating an interface that contains properties of `V1` and then inheriting `V1` and `V2` declarations (generated with sqlmetal.exe) from it (thanks to partial classes!):

```
public interface IV {
    int P1 {get;set;}
    int P2 {get;set;}
}

public partial class V1: IV { }
public partial class V2: IV { }
```

then modified `GetData()`:

```
IEnumerable<IV> GetData(Func<MyDataContext, IEnumerable<IV>> MyFilter filter, MySortOrder order) {}
```

so i can pass either `myDataContext.V1` or `myDataContext.V2` entity sets in and cast the result. Do not know if it's best solution but it's DRY and I'm happy.